# Find the smallest integer $n$ with $\tau(n)=a$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find the smallest integer $n$ with $\tau(n)=a$ with $\tau(n)$ the number of dividers of n.

1. $\tau(n)=1$
2. $\tau(n)=2$
3. $\tau(n)=3$
4. $\tau(n)=6$

The soluion is given by:
[image]
The book does not give a solution method, I just tried it by trail and error. What is the best method for such an excercice?

Comment: It does give a solution method. Not giving a solution method would've been "a) 1, b) 2, c) 4, d) 12, e) 192, f) 45360". What they have done in your image definitely counts as giving solution method.

Comment: Just a remark: "Divisors of $n$", not "dividers".

Comment: In order to find the number of divisors of a given number you need to find the prime factor of the given number for example if $ N = 12 $ prime factor is $ 2^{2} * 3^{1} $and thus the total number of divisors is $(2+1)*(1+1) = 6. $You can do this in a reverse way. So in the book, it is given $n = pq^{2}.$ for more information see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function

Comment: for 100 prime factor is $ 2 * 2 * 5 * 5$ so the number is $ 2^{(4+1)} * 3^{(4 + 1)} * 5 ^ {(1+1)} * 7 ^ {(1 + 1)} = 2^{4} * 3^{4} *5 ^{1} * 7^{1} = 45360$

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by factoring the number into prime factor.Read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic , SO there is only one unique to factorize a number into prime factors.
Suppose Given number is N for unique way to reduce this into prime factor is $p1^{e1}*p2^{e2}......pn^{e^{m}}$ Here $p1 < p2 < p3....$. Now the total number of divisors of this number is $ (e1 + 1)*(e2 + 1) *(e3 + 1).....(em +1)$ So if you are given a number of divisors of Nyou can easily find the number by factoring it.
Just take $τ(n)=3$ so prime factor of 3 is 3 and it is = $(e1 + 1)$. Now put this in form o$p1^{e1}*p2^{e2}......pn^{e^{m}}$ Here $p1 < p2 < p3....$. it will be $2^{2} $ whic is equal to 4 and hence 4 is the smallest number with 3 divisors which are $ 1, 2 ,4$ . Hope this helps.